# Passing arguments to R script in command line (shell/bash): what to do when column names contain tilde (~)

Tags: r, bash, shell, command-line, rscript

I'm utilizing `Rscript` to run an R script through bash, and I want to specify arguments to be passed to functions within the script itself. Specifically, I want to pass arguments that specify:

- path to data file (`.csv`) and
- certain column names in that data file.

I run into a problem when the column names include the tilde sign (`~`). I've tried wrapping the column names with backticks but still unsuccessful.

### Example

I want to write a script that takes in a data file in `.csv` format and plots a histogram for one variable according to the user's choice.

#### Here's my function:

```r
plot_histogram <- function(path_to_input, x_var) {
  
  data_raw <- read.csv(file = path_to_input)
  
  path_to_output_folder <- dirname(path_to_input)
  
  png(filename = paste0(path_to_output_folder, "/", "output_plot.png"))
  
  hist(as.numeric(na.omit(data_raw[[x_var]])), main = "histogram", xlab = "my_var")
  
  replicate(dev.off(), n = 20)
}
```

#### Let's run it on some fake data

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(age = sample(20:80, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

write.csv(df, "some_age_data.csv")

plot_histogram(path_to_input = "some_age_data.csv",
               x_var = "age")
```

As intended, I get a `.png` file with the plot, saved to the same directory where the `.csv` is at
[image: hist]

#### Now customize an R script to be run from command line

***`plot_histogram.R`***

```r
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

## same function as above
plot_histogram <- function(path_to_input, x_var) {
  
  data_raw <- read.csv(file = path_to_input)
  path_to_output_folder <- dirname(path_to_input)
  png(filename = paste0(path_to_output_folder, "/", "output_plot.png"))
  hist(as.numeric(na.omit(data_raw[[x_var]])), main = "histogram", xlab = "my_var")
  replicate(dev.off(), n = 20)
}

plot_histogram(path_to_input = args[1], x_var = args[2])
```

Then run via command line using `Rscript`

```sh
$ Rscript --vanilla plot_histogram.R /../../../some_age_data.csv "age"
```

Works too!

#### However, things break if the column name contains tilde

**Step 1: create fake data**

```r
library(tibble)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(`age-blah~value` = sample(20:80, size = 100, replace = T))

write.csv(df, "some_age_data.csv")
```

**Step 2: Using `Rscript`:**

```sh
$ Rscript --vanilla plot_histogram.R /../../../some_age_data.csv "age-blah~value"
```

> Error in hist.default(as.numeric(na.omit(data_raw[[x_var]])), main =
> "histogram",  :   invalid number of 'breaks' Calls: plot_histogram -> hist -> hist.default Execution halted

### Bottom Line

When using `Rscript`, how can I pass an argument that specifies a column name containing tilde? Alternatively, how can I work around `.csv` files that have such a format of tilde in column names, within the framework of `Rscript`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *are* successfully passing an argument that specifies a column name containing tilde. However, `read.csv` has "fixed" the column names so it doesn't actually contain a tilde.

`read.csv` is silently converting the column name to `age.blah.value`. Use `check.names = FALSE` to make it `age-blah~value`.

```
data_raw <- read.csv(file = path_to_input, check.names = FALSE)
```